# Percent stacked barchart failed in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to analyse smoker types in different years and make a percentage barplot, which should look like the picture below:

[image]

```
ggplot(data = subset(Cd_no_110, !is.na(SmokeType)), aes(x=Check_Year, y=SmokeType, fill=SmokeType)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Everything looks fine here. However, when I tried to turn this picture into a percentage barplot

```
ggplot(data = subset(Cd_no_110, !is.na(SmokeType)), aes(x=Check_Year, y=SmokeType, fill=SmokeType)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

it turned out to be this:

[image]

How do i fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we don't have your data, the issue is that you map a factor or character (aka `SmokeType`) on the `y` aesthetic, which when used with `geom_col` gives weird charts and axes scales which is evident from both of your plots. From your charts and code you want a barchart of the counts, which can be achieved by dropping `y=` and switching to `geom_bar`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`.

First, let's replicate your issue by mapping a `factor` on `y`. Here the y scale and axis labels clearly show us that soewnthing is wrong:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), factor(am), fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_col()

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), factor(am), fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")

p1 + p2
```

[image]

And the issue could be fixed by dropping the `y` aes and by switching to `geom_bar`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image]